# How to plot a pd.Series and use the color for each point coming from another data source?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a `pd.Series` called `data` that I would like to plot, and I have another series with the same index as `data` called `colors`. I would to plot `data`, and for each point of the plot, I would like color it based on the corresponding value in the Series `colors` (using some color map). Is it possible to do it in `matplotlib` or `seaborn`?

Comment: Can you clarify what sort of plot?  I assume scatter plot, but how is this working with a single `Series` ?

Comment: _Is it possible to do it in `matplotlib` or `seaborn`?_ Unfortunately, when it comes to programming most things are possible. Do you have a specific question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with `matplotlib` like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.Series(range(5))
colors = pd.Series(['r','g','b','b','r'])

plt.scatter(data.index, data, c=colors)
plt.show()
```

[image]

or if the series color is more like group number (not colors), you can do it with `seaborn` like :

```
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.Series(range(5))
colors = pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 2, 0])

sns.scatterplot(data.index, data, hue=colors)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if colors is numerical values, say from 0 to 1?

Comment: @motam79 the seaborn option does not care about the values themselves, just which one are the same together, so if it is `pd.Series([0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0])` instead it would give similar result